# How to get dummies without prefix?

Tags: pandas

I want to get dummies from two different columns, but without any prefix.

Data illustration:

```
   X    Y
 123  AAA
 456  BBB
 123  AAA
 789  CCC
```

Expected result:

```
   X    Y  789  456  123  CCC  BBB  AAA
 123  AAA    0    0    1    0    0    1
 456  BBB    0    1    0    0    1    0
 123  AAA    0    0    1    0    0    1
 789  CCC    1    0    0    1    0    0
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `prefix=''` and `prefix_sep=''` parameters. Also if it is possible some of the columns are numeric convert them to strings:

```
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.astype(str), prefix='', prefix_sep=''))
print(df)

     X    Y  123  456  789  AAA  BBB  CCC
0  123  AAA    1    0    0    1    0    0
1  456  BBB    0    1    0    0    1    0
2  123  AAA    1    0    0    1    0    0
3  789  CCC    0    0    1    0    0    1
```